# How to enable windows-style Ctrl+Backspace in msysgit (git bash)?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, msysgit

I would like to configure my msysgit environment to use windows-style backspace shortcuts, i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes a word.

I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094828/msysgit-bash-how-to-enable-ctrlleft-right-arrows

which describes how to use inputrc to use windows-style cnrl+arrow key shortcuts. I tried repeating the process for cnrl+backspace, i.e., pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> and using the output as a parameter for `backward-word` (also tried `backward-kill-word`)  without success.

Note: My output for getting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> is "^?" on msysgit. I tried both "\e?" and "\e^?" as parameters to no avail.

I can't seem to find any more information on this. Any tips would be appreciated. I know <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd> does what I want, but that's not what I'm after.

Thanks,